# How to set custom validator for a property that return Task using Fluent Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to set a custom validator on a property which return a list of objects asynchronously

```
public Task<IList<ComplexType>> Property { get; set; }
```

Is there a way other than setting it without calling `.Result` on the property?

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Property.Result).SetValidator(new MyComplexValidator());
```

Comment: Properties shouldn't be asynchronous: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay In my case, the property returns a value that is expensive to create, so should be cached for future use. The asynchronous operation executed only once: the first time it’s requested. After the operation completes, the result of the operation will be cached and returned immediately

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Johnathan comment, properties shouldn't be asynchronous, and I highly recommend that you revisit your design.

But to answer your question, there's no way really to call RuleForEach() on a Task because it requires an enumerable, and a Task<IList> is not enumerable. As a workaround, you can use MustAsync() to trigger the task and then use another validator to validate your complex type. Check the example below.

```
public class ComplexType
{
}

public class SomeType
{
    public Task<IList<ComplexType>> Property { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<ComplexType>
{
    public ComplexTypeValidator()
    {
        //Your Validation Logic Here
    }
}

public class SomeTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeType>
{
    public SomeTypeValidator(IValidator<ComplexType> complexTypeValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Property)
            .MustAsync(async (property, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                var propertyResult = await property;
                return propertyResult.Aggregate(true, (result, o) => result && complexTypeValidator.Validate(o).IsValid);
            });
    }
}
```

In this example, I used MustAsync() to trigger the property asynchronously and used another validator for ComplexType. Unfortunately, you can't use RuleForEach() within MustAsync as well so you've to loop through the list yourself like in the example.